# Can I save StackExchange API content to my own DB

Tags: support, stack-exchange, api, terms-of-service

Could not fully understand it from the [StackExchange API terms of use](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use), or the [StackExchange terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Can I save content I retrieve through the StackExchange API to my own DB and use the data for commercial use?

Comment: The answer is likely yes. The user content served is going to be subject to the CC-Wiki license, which allows any use as long as attribution guidelines are followed. See "3. Subscriber content" in http://stackexchange.com/legal.